# How to add css to linked rails imge

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

So I want to add css to a linked image that I created with rails.
Before I added the link I had the following:

```
<div class ="resize">
        <%= image_tag listing.image.url %>
   </div>
```

My Css is as follows:

```
/*resize container */
    .resize {
    width: 250x;
    height: 250px;
}

/* resize images */
.resize img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now I created a clickable/linked image and have the following code.

```
<div class ="resize">
        <%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url), listing %>
   </div>
```

Now the css does not work anymore.
How do I add the css to the linked image?

Update---
More information: The listing and the images are uploaded and created by users that sign up on my website. So I do not have the images on my computer.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url), listing_path(listing) %>
```

This will create the HTML code below (example):

```
<a href="/listing"><img src="/path/image.extention" alt="image" /></a>
```

So you can add css looks like

```
/*resize container */
.resize {
    width: 250x;
    height: 250px;
}


/* resize link */
.resize a {
 text-decoration :none;   
}

/* resize images */
.resize a img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Or add a class to link looks like :

```
<%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url), listing_path(listing), :class => 'link-class' %>
```

The result html :

```
<a href="/listing" class="link-class"><img src="/path/image.extention" alt="image" /></a>
```

add a class to link and image looks like :

```
<%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url, :class => 'image-class'), listing_path(listing), :class => 'link-class' %>
```

The result html :

```
<a href="/listing" class="link-class"><img src="/path/image.extention" alt="image" class="image-class" /></a>
```

Comment: So for you first solution <a href="/listing"><img src="/path/image.extention" alt="image" /></a> I do not have the image. The image will be uploaded by a user that signs up on my website and creates a listing. For you second solution, adding a class to the link, I don't think it works how I want it. Resize is the container and resize img makes the image fit into that container.

Comment: The problem on your question is **add the css to the linked image**   , my answer for to solve your problem. So what do you mean about you uploaded by a user, what do you want now? add some style to linked image or else?

Comment: **Resize is the container and resize img makes the image fit into that container.** my solution can do it.

Comment: It's an etsy like page that displays Images that are uploaded by other users. When clicking the image you are brought to another page that shows you information about the item. Thats why I cannot use <img src="/path/image.extention" alt="image" />

Comment: You don't use it, cause that is the html result of your have but you should use this `<%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url), listing_path(listing) %>` and the css on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a space between `class` and it's name

```
<div class="resize">
    <%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url), listing %>
</div>
```

also, `listing` may be crashing to - it should say something like `listing_path(listing)`

Comment: the resize class is only the container. I want the image to fit into that container. Also the listing refers to a listing other users that signed up to my page create

Comment: Your code as you showed above should work. It's correct. Make sure you have no typos.

Comment: It's not working because the .resize img refers to an image. The code that I created now however is a link. So the .resize img does not apply anymore.

Comment: Yeah, I was right. Your code is fine. Its just full of typos. You're also missing "p" when you define width. Right now you have "250x" X what? here you have fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SX3Z6/3/. Go back to codeacademy

Comment: Also, using both height and width set to 100% is a bad practice. Will distort all images that are not square

Comment: The  jsfiddle.net/SX3Z6/3 works because in the code it says "<img src="https://i.imgflip.com/1bim.jpg"/>". I do not have a direct image source since others upload the images.

Comment: What are you talking about? If someone uploads image that is not square, than fixed dimensions you have set will distort the image changing it to square. It has nothing to do with who uploaded the image.